# Deduce $\lvert ab\rvert = \lvert ba\rvert$ for all $a,b\in G$ where $G$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It has been awhile since I took Abstract Algebra and decided to go back through Dummit and Foote. However, I have come across a problem I can't seem to figure out.

---

> If $x$ and $g$ are elements of the group $G$, prove that $\lvert x\rvert = \lvert g^{-1}xg\rvert$. Deduce that $\lvert ab\rvert = \lvert ba\rvert$ for all $a,b\in G$.

---

Let $\lvert x\rvert = n$. Then
  \begin{align*}
    x^n & = (g^{-1}xg)^n\\
        & = \underbrace{(g^{-1}xg)\cdots (g^{-1}xg)}_{n\text{ times}}\\
        & = g^{-1}x^ng\\
        & = g^{-1}eg\\
        & = g^{-1}g\\
        & = e
  \end{align*}
  Thus, $\lvert g^{-1}xg\rvert = n = \lvert x\rvert$. Now, suppose $\lvert x\rvert = \infty$ and $\lvert g^{-1}xg\rvert = n$. Then
  $$
  g^{-1}x^ng = e\Rightarrow gg^{-1}x^ngg^{-1} = geg^{-1}\Rightarrow
  x^n = e
  $$
  which is a contradiction. That is, if $\lvert x\rvert = \infty$, then so does $\lvert g^{-1}xg\rvert$.

---

The problem is I can't seem to deduce $\lvert ab\rvert = \lvert ba\rvert$. I imagine it isn't difficult, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Let $x=ab$ and $g=b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* Find $g$ such that $g^{-1}(ab)g=ba$.

Comment: From above, we have that $\lvert ab\rvert = \lvert g^{-1}(ab)g\rvert$.  \begin{align*}                                           
    \lvert ab\rvert & = \lvert g^{-1}(ab)g\rvert\tag{Let $g = b^{-1}a$}\\     
                    & = \lvert ba^{-1}(ab)b^{-1}a\rvert\\                       
                    & = \lvert ba\rvert                                         
  \end{align*}

Comment: $g = b^{-1}$ will do, though $g = b^{-1}a$ also works.

Answer (score 3):

The key idea is that $\,ab\,$ and $\,ba\,$ are *conjugate,* i.e. $\, ab = g^{-1} ba\, g\,$ for $\, g =\, \ldots\, $ But [conjugation is always a group isomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/250264/242) $ $ Here it restricts to the subgroup isomorphism $\ \langle ab\rangle\cong \langle ba\rangle.\,$ Thus both groups have the same order, hence their generators have the same order $\,|ab| = |ba|.$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more direct proof. If $\text{ord}(ab)=n$ is the order of $ab$, then

$$
\underbrace{(ab)(ab)...(ab)(ab)}_{n\text{ times}}=a\underbrace{(ba)(ba)..(ba)}_{n-1\text{ times}}b=1$$
$$\begin{align}(ba)^{n-1}&=(ba)^{-1} \\
(ba)^n&=1
\end{align}
$$

So $\text{ord}(ba)\leq\text{ord}(ab)$. By symmetry, $\text{ord}(ba)\geq\text{ord}(ab)$, so $\text{ord}(ba)=\text{ord}(ab)$.

Comment: An even easier version of this: $a=ea=(ab)^na$ (using $(ab)^n=e$) $=a(ba)^n$ (rearranging terms).